# Asp.net website to web application project (Old_App_Code folder)

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I am converting a asp.net website (Visual studio 2010) to web application project (Visual studio 2010). Once I convert it I see a 'Old_App_Code' folder. How to convert the class files in that folder to WAP? Do I need create a seperate class library for those?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

after reading a ton about it and reading suggestions of using the Razor Generator et cetera, I couldn't figure it out.  so I just renamed the Old_App_Code folder back to App_Code and my application just works

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx
'Because ASP.NET dynamically compiles all classes in the App_Code folder, you should not store classes in the folder that you compile as part of your Web application project. If you do, the class will be compiled two times. The first time will be as part of the Visual Studio Web application project assembly, and the second time will be at run time by ASP.NET. This can cause a "could not load type" exception, which occurs because there are duplicate type names in the application.'